# extreme points on cumulative sequence.

Tags: convex-hulls

Given a sequence of vectors $(a_1, 1), \cdots, (a_i, 1), \cdots, (a_n, 1)$ such that $ a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

And my interest is to find extreme points(extreme points of the convex hull) of the cumulative sequence $B = (\sum_{i=1}^1 a_i, \sum_{i=1}^1 1), \cdots,  (\sum_{i=1}^j a_i, \sum_{i=1}^j 1), \cdots, (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i, \sum_{i=1}^n 1)$.

And my hypothesis is: suppose $a_k = max(\{a_1, \cdots, a_i, \cdots, a_n\})$, then $b_k$ must be extreme points of $CH(B)$.

Is this a valid claim?

If so,  can I apply this method in a recursive fashion separate the $A$ into $A_1, A_k$ and $A_k, A_n$ and apply similar argument to obtain the upper hull of $B$ ?

Comment: at least the second part is not true. if the recursive works, then every point is going to be on the boundary.  since for every interval, there is a max.

Comment: sorry, i was meant for extreme point. thanks for pointing out

Comment: I run a few simulations, the claims seems to be true